# Помогите с выводом комментариев ( дерево )

Tags: php, массивы, дерево

Есть массив, первый параметр id, второй parent id и текст

```
$arr = array(
    array(1, 1, "Comment 1"),
    array(2, 1, "Comment 2"),
    array(3, 2, "Comment 3"),
    array(4, 1, "Comment 4"),
    array(5, 2, "Comment 5"),
    array(6, 3, "Comment 6"),
    array(7, 7, "Comment 7")
);
```

А результат должен быть таким

```
Comment 1
    Comment 2
        Comment 3
            Comment 6
        Comment 5
    Comment 4
Comment 7
```

Второй день пытаюсь решить и все мои решения дают один результат, вывод под parent_id соответствующий комментарий, но порядок тогда меняется или бесконечная рекурсия

Comment: Где результаты ваших попыток за 2 дня?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если перестроить массив по-другому, будет гораздо проще

```
$res = [];

foreach($arr as $i) {
  if ($i[0] == $i[1]) $i[1] = 0;
  $res[$i[1]][] = [ $i[0], $i[2] ];  
}

makeTree($res);

function makeTree($arr, $root = 0) {
    echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach($arr[$root] as $i) {
        echo "<li>\n";
        echo $i[1];
        if (isset($arr[$i[0]])) MakeTree($arr, $i[0]);
        echo "</li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
Comment 1<ul>
<li>
Comment 2<ul>
<li>
Comment 3<ul>
<li>
Comment 6</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
Comment 5</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
Comment 4</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
Comment 7</li>
</ul>
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/907421)